# Create a list of value depend on other list of data (google sheet script)

Tags: list, google-sheets-api

Hi i need to create a list of value depending on other list of data. Here is an example :

```
A         |     B
------------------------
Harry     |  Golden Snitch
Ron       |  Quaffle
Fred      |  Bludger
George    |  Bludger
Percy     |  Quaffle
Alicia    |  Quaffle
```

This represent my excel sheet i need to create a list of value A depending on B filter.
I need to keep all name who used "Quaffle". that list should be :

```
Ron / Percy / Alicia
```

I know how to do this in formula i found this :
`=FILTER($A$1:$A$6;$B$1:$B$6 = "Quaffle")`

But i literraly can't find how to do this in google script can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Pick your data by using `.getValues()`. This will give you an array of row data. [[Row 1], [Row 2]...]
Loop through this nested array and find if any row satisfy `if (colBvalue == "Quaffle")`  condition. Then put it in an empty result array.

```
function myfilter() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
 var data = sheet.getRange("A1:B6").getValues();
 var result = [];
  for (var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    var colAvalue = data[i][0]
    var colBvalue = data[i][1]
    if (colBvalue == "Quaffle") {
      result.push(colAvalue)
    }
  }
  // do whatever you want in this result 
  // [Ron, Percy, Alicia]
  Logger.log(result)
}
```